# Using attributes to observe a variable

Tags: c#, reflection, attributes

I am planning to make something like setting an attribute to a variable in any class and be able to observe the changes to the variable from another class is this possible. Basically what I am trying is tagging a variable with a certain name and collect all the named variables and display it in screen and be able to change the observe and consume the changes to the variable.  Is this possible with attributes or any other feature in c#?

Thanks for your time!

Fl@my!

Comment: looking for this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd990377(v=vs.110).aspx?

Comment: Hello @Ehsan IObserver seems to be a good one while listening to the whole class of a known type but the problem is  
1) I dont want to observe to the whole class
2) I jus want to observe to individual variables inside object.
3) variable 1 can be in class 10 and variable 2 can be in class 30... that is the reason im looking for possibilities with attributes
. Is there a way to do with IObserver that Im missing?

Comment: you can use INotifyPropertyChanged then

Comment: actually I am looking into a solution which doesnt need extra efforts to plugin into another project, using above 2 methods i have to write more classes depending on what variable/class I am observing?!